# What is the life expectancy of a yorkie?

Tags: lifespan

I know that various dog breeds have different life expectancies. Has there been research done on specifically the Yorkshire Terrier breed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average life expectancy for standard size Yorkies is 13-16 years; 14.5 is the median age. The average life expectancy for females is a little longer than it is for male's (1.5 years longer).

It's important to note though that teacup Yorkie's (those under 4lbs) have a shorter lifespan - just 7-9 years on average. This is largely due to the fact that they're at increased risk for traumatic injury due to their small size.

The [Yorkie Info Center](http://www.yorkieinfocenter.com/yorkshire-terrier-life-span) offers more information on the research that's been conducted, specific to this breed.